# Specific word followed by full stop followed by another group RegEx

Tags: regex, vb.net

Hi I'm having a little trouble with a regular expression.

I tested:
`([Version]+)\.([.0-9A-Za-z]+)`
With:

> /Downloads/Documents/Access MDB - DEV Version.2.1.4.zip

This worked in [RegexHero](http://regexhero.net/tester/), my groups seemed fine (sort of).

However when I'm searching through HTML source code it returns things like:

> e.axd

How would I get 2 groups:

1. Version.
2. 2.1.4.zip

Or even one group?

1. Version.2.1.4.zip

I'm puzzling over this, regular expressions aren't my strong suit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using Avinash's answer as a baseline I found the solution as:

`(version.*\.zip)`

This matches what I needed

> version.2.1.4.zip

Answer (score 1):

`Version.2.1.4.zip` in one group,

```
^.* (.*)$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sB6pV0/2)

Comment: Works beautifully on the example I gave, but as I mentioned, when using a HTML page filled with other code it doesn't work.

 `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/corev4.css?rev=iIikGkMuXBs8CWzKDAyjsQ%3D%3D"/>`

It does not work as it should, note how I wanted to use the full word "Version." as I am pulling the same file from the web page once a month.

Comment: you could use `Version\S*`

Comment: I will have to give it a try when I'm at work on Monday, thanks Avninash. I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: @Jezzabeanz sure bye:-)

Comment: Hi Avinash, 
I tried the `Version\S*` but I couldn't get it to work (like I said, Regexp isn't my strongest area). I did get the solution though: `(version.*\.zip)` returns exactly what I need to, but your answer put me on the right path. Thank you.

Comment: if you ask me. I'll get it for you.. :-)